# How do you prevent Thread ending notifications in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ive got a lot of threads and i dont want to be informed on the console when a thread ends, howcani stop this being outputted?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the output window, click Thread Exit, and accept answers to your questions by clicking the hollow check.